# Windows Form run website without address bar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, process.start, address-bar

I've seen a lot of examples using JavaScript to run a popup window to remove address bar. My issue is I want to run a full website [that I've created in ASP.net] without the address bar visible from a Windows Form application.

I've tried:

```
Dim objIE As Object 'InternetExplorer 'or as object - if you want to keep it lite and don't add the reference

    objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        objIE.AddressBar = False
        objIE.MenuBar = False
        objIE.ToolBar = False
        .Navigate2(Address)
    End With
    objIE.Navigate = Address
```

but I get an error at CreateObject of `Cannot create ActiveX component`.

So my current working code to run the website is:

```
Dim process As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Dim sInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(Address)
    Process.Start(sInfo)
```

However, the address bar is visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you just run it in full screen where the address bar will be temporarily hidden? Or are you trying to remove the bar completely.

Comment: I want zero access to the address bar for various reason and need to run the website from a windows form for other reasons @Busse

Comment: I read that `processwindowstyle.hidden` requires `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False` but that didn't do anything either @Busse

Comment: Understood - when you step through the first code, with the IE object, does the error occur immediately on `objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`?

Comment: yes it does. @Busse

Comment: @Busse and the `IE.Menu....` and etc is suppose to be `ObjIE`

Comment: hmm modern browsers should not allow you to do that due to the popularity of phishing web sites...can't you just use a webbrowser control?

Comment: since my asp.net website has various window popups and tab openings, I couldn't use webbrowser. @ShengJiang蒋晟

Comment: you can handle the DWebBrowserEvents2::NewWindow2 event to display popups in tabs inside your winform app.

Comment: Awesomium will let you display the addressbar optionally

Comment: have you add SHDocVw as a reference?

Comment: @Werdna I don't have that listed in COM, Projects, Assemblies and etc. Where do I find that?

Comment: I think its under internet explorer within com

Answer (score 0):

That code should work fine, as I just tested it myself.  I would say start a fresh VB file (console application/windows form, whichever you'd like) and try to run just these:

```
Dim objIE as Object
objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   With objIE
       .Visible = True
   End With
```

If it does not run from there, then your best bet is to try to "Reset" your internet explorer, which can be done through the Settings/Options.  I've done this in the past and it allowed to work.  The fact that you cannot create the object is the concerning part, as that's being written correctly and when I run that on my PC it works.

Give those two a shot (try a fresh file, and reset internet explorer). And let me know if that works.

Comment: Ran that code in a new Windows Form and got same error. Reset Internet explorer and ran again same error :/

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015. maybe that could be an issue?

Comment: I see at this link https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/482542/microsoft-visualbasic-dll-unhandled-exception about how he needed to install something; however I have everything installed ..hmm

Comment: Everything I read while researching it for you briefly all ended up being system issues (bad installations or images). I'm on my way out of work and won't be able to research anymore so unfortunately I'll be stopping at this point. Sorry it didn't help you and I hope someone here can help or point you in the right direction! Good luck!